# Integrate Sophos Firewall with Azure AD (openssl)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openssl, openssl-engine

please help me on this error
Did as in the bellow link,
[https://community.sophos.com/sophos-xg-firewall/f/recommended-reads/125872/sophos-firewall-integrate-sophos-firewall-with-azure-ad#mcetoc_1etvmh9lj1]

openssl x509 -req -extensions client_server_ssl -extfile azureAD-eku.conf -in azureADldapssl.csr -CA azureADca.pem -CAkey azureADca.key -CAcreateserial -out azureADcert.crt -days 365

(Can't open "azureAD-eku.conf" for reading, No such file or directory
30370000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(azureAD-eku.conf, r)
30370000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:)

I need to  Integrate Sophos Firewall with Azure AD

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to Integrate Sophos Firewall with Azure AD.**

Follow the below steps to integrate **Sophos Firewall** with **Azure AD**

1. Download and install **Open SSL**  [here](https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL_Light-3_0_7.exe)
2. Once install the **Open SSL**  set the path in environment variables.

> Path:C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin

[image]

3. Check the **Open SSL** install status by checking the version, like below.
4. 

[image]

5. Now generate a **certificate** and **private key** using below cmd.

> openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

[image]

Successfully created **Certificate** and **Key**, the **cert.pem** & **key.pem** will be saved to the **Open SSL Terminal** directory.

```
Ex: C:\Users\your username
```

[image]

You need to configure the firewall to use the **Certificate** and **Key**, which you created earlier with **Open SSL**.

1.Now log in to the **Sophos** firewall interface.
2. You can navigate to the **Certificates** option and upload the created **cert.pem** and **key.pem** files.

Now configure the firewall to use Azure AD authentication.

Create an application in **Azure AD**, like below.

**Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App registrations >Manage > New registration.**

> Note: Enter the firewall's URL in the "Sign-on URL" field.

[image]

You can fetch the **Application ID**, like below.

**Azure AD portal > App registrations > Overview**

[image]

Now add the **Azure AD Authentication** on firewall by providing the **Application ID** and **URL** of **Azure AD instance**

You can also refer **Sophos Community** : [Sophos Firewall: Integrate Sophos Firewall with Azure AD](https://community.sophos.com/sophos-xg-firewall/f/recommended-reads/125872/sophos-firewall-integrate-sophos-firewall-with-azure-ad)